# Timer in ForkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have an API with 3 GET calls.

1. Get environments
2. Get products
3. Get status for specific product in specific environment

What I am trying to do is to poll the status of each product in each environment every 5 minutes, so that I can display the data in a table which is refreshed.

The call to fetch envs and products should be executed once, since this is static information.

```
let envs = this.http.get('http://my-api/envs);
let products = this.http.get('http://my-api/products);

forkJoin([envs, products]).subscribe(results => {
  //the code below should be executed every 5 mins and store the results in array
  results[0].forEach(env => {
    results[1].forEach(product => {
      this.http.get('http://my-api/status/${env}/${product}')
    })
  })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could wrap the `forkJoin` in a `setInterval(() => {}, 300000);`

Comment: save the setInterval call to a variable, so you can cancel it if needed. (otherwise the calls could be stacking up if a previous call has not yet finished, but with 5 minutes it might never occur...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what this accomplishes, but it runs the code in the subscription every five minutes. Well, more accurately it calls the `forkJoin` every 5 minutes. If the `forkJoin` takes a variable amount of time to execute that might shift the time a bit. Otherwise, you could call forkJoin early and delay the results to the five-minute mark with `delay` and some math on `Date()`

```js
const fiveMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 5;
timer(0, fiveMinutes).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => forkJoin({
     envs: this.http.get('http://my-api/envs'),
     products: this.http.get('http://my-api/products')
  }))
).subscribe(({envs, products}) => {
  envs.forEach(env => {
    products.forEach(product => {
      // This http call doesn't do anything ?
      this.http.get('http://my-api/status/${env}/${product}') 
    })
  })
});
```

#### Update # 1: interval on final calls.

This one calls your `this.http.get('http://my-api/status/${env}/${product}')` calls every 5 minutes and sends the results to the subscription as an array.

This isn't tested for obvious reasons. But it should provide a good starting point.

```js
const fiveMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 5;
forkJoin({
  envs: this.http.get('http://my-api/envs'),
  products: this.http.get('http://my-api/products')
}).pipe(
  map(({env, products}) => 
    envs.map(env =>
      products.map(product =>
        this.http.get('http://my-api/status/${env}/${product}') 
      )
    ).flat()
  ),
  mergeMap(statusCalls => timer(0, fiveMinutes).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => forkJoin(statusCalls))
  ))
).subscribe(statusCallsResults => {
  //** Update your view with results **//
})
```

If you really want your subscription as set up before, that might look like this:

```js
const fiveMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 5;
forkJoin({
  envs: this.http.get('http://my-api/envs'),
  products: this.http.get('http://my-api/products')
}).pipe(
  mergeMap(res => timer(0, fiveMinutes).pipe(
    map(_ => res)
  ))
).subscribe(({envs, products}) => {
  // This is called every five minutes
  envs.forEach(env => {
    products.forEach(product => {
      // This http call doesn't do anything ?
      this.http.get('http://my-api/status/${env}/${product}') 
    })
  })
});
```

#### Update # 2: Error Handling

`forkJoin` will fail if any of its inner observables fail. You can deal with this in many ways. The most basic is to transform an errored stream into a stream that emits null and completes successfully. Then forkJoin will have `null` in every array position with an error.

That might look like this:

```js
const fiveMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 5;
forkJoin({
  envs: this.http.get('http://my-api/envs'),
  products: this.http.get('http://my-api/products')
}).pipe(
  map(({env, products}) => 
    envs.map(env =>
      products.map(product =>
        this.http.get('http://my-api/status/${env}/${product}').pipe(
          catchError(err => of(null))
        )
      )
    ).flat()
  ),
  mergeMap(statusCalls => timer(0, fiveMinutes).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => forkJoin(statusCalls))
  ))
).subscribe(statusCallsResults => {
  //** Update your view with results **//
})
```

Error code 500 isn't very descriptive. You might look into the retry operator to retry the request when it fails. That can be combined with `catchError`.

Not getting that error from the server in the first place is up to you.

Comment: thanks. As you mentioned this code calls the `forkJoin` every 5 minutes, but I dont want that. I only want to poll the status and thats it. Because the environments and products is kind of static information but the status could change overtime

Comment: Hmmm, made an update that only makes the status calls every 5 minutes.

Comment: This is great help thanks! One thing, I get an error for flat(), did you mean flatMap instead?

Comment: Just flattening the resulting array since it's nested. You can check compatibility here and use an alternative if you like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Property 'flat' does not exist on type `Observable<StatusModel>[][]`. I cannot have flat operator in 2D array

Comment: stackblitz of .flat() on 2d array: https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-flat?file=index.ts

Comment: yeah sorry I meant on an Observable of 2D array.

Comment: flattening as an operation works over any 2d array. It doesn't care it's numbers, objects, observables, whatever. If you don't have it available, just use one of the alternatives from the Mozilla link earlier.

Comment: Case-in-point, here's a stackblitz with observables: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rxjs-playground-jhasd6iakj-zhzofn

Comment: yeah Im really sorry, I had to change my compilerOptions in tsConfig file. Your solution looks fine, but I dont reach the console.log statement because some calls are failing with error code 500. Is there a possibility to overcome this? Im referring to the first snippet of update #1

Comment: Added a 2nd update for basic error handling